# Reboot AD computers one at a time through powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to reboot all computers in AD one at a time(excluding my computer), confirming that each one has restarted before restarting the next one. Once a system has rebooted, I want to see it's IP address and name. Below is my attempt but I think I'm doing something wrong since its not working. The main error I receive is:

```
 Get-WMIObject: cannot validate argument on parameter 'computerName'. The argument is null or empty
 + $serverobj = gmi Win32_operatingsystem -computername $i.server
```

Code:

```
$servers= Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

foreach($i in $servers) {
 Write-Host "Rebooting:" $i.server "..."

 $serverObj = gwmi Win32_operatingsystem -computer $i.server

 $status = $serverObj.reboot()

 if ($status.ReturnValue = "0") {
      Write-Host "Reboot successful."
 } else {
      Write-Host "Reboot failed."
 }
do {
    Start-Sleep -s 2 }  # this will wait for 2 seconds 
while (Test-Connection $servers -count 1 | select @{Name="Computername";Expression={$_.Address}},Ipv4Address)
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? They may be "clear" to you but you're the one at your console, we can't see them.

Comment: I apologize. I did not mean errors.

Comment: Well, what does "not working" mean then?  What isn't working?  What *is* working?  Are the servers not rebooting?  Is the script rebooting everything without waiting?  Is the script rebooting the wrong computers? Is the IP address not displaying?

Comment: Hey I've added the error. Also, I am fairly new with powershell!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one *seems* simple enough for your immediate problem:

```
$serverObj = gwmi Win32_operatingsystem -computer $i.server
```

should be

```
$serverObj = gwmi Win32_operatingsystem -computer $i
```

`$i` has no properties beyond what a `[string]` has. PowerShell, by default, will allow you to attempt to get properties that do not exist and a null will be returned in that case. `Get-WMIObject` however cannot work with that for the parameter `-Computer`. The error was pretty specific.

There is a way you can try and catch these issues but using `Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0` for example. From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx)

> 2.0
>
> -- Prohibits references to uninitialized variables (including uninitialized variables in strings).
>
> -- Prohibits references to non-existent properties of an object.
>
> -- Prohibits function calls that use the syntax for calling methods.
>
> -- Prohibits a variable without a name (${}).

---

You refer to the *main error you are receiving* ... does that mean you have more?

Your `while` condition seems flawed. You should be trying to evaluate a boolean expression but you are just returning data. Even if the ping failed data should be returned and that could invalidate the logic of your loop. Consider using the switch `-Quiet` for `test-connection`. You are also checking the pings of *all* `$servers` instead of just `$i`.

```
while (!(Test-Connection $i -count 1 -Quiet))
```

maybe...

Comment: Hey Matt! making that change fixed it and is no longer giving any other errors. However, The script just gets stuck at "Reboot Successful" and does not test the connection and move onto the next computer. Any Idea why?

Comment: @NebelzCheez You might have missed a recent edit. Look at the bottom of my answer. Your do while is flawed I think.

Comment: Oops my bad. I made the following changes and the script is now looping through the computers. But still not showing the output of test-connection statement.  (!(Test-Connection $i -count 1 -Quiet | select @{Name="Computername";Expression={$_.Address}},Ipv4Address))

Comment: You have it in a while statement.... you are not going to see it nor would you want to in that case. If you want output then inside the do loop would be the spot for it.